# xrdp filter setting for fail2ban

Tags: python, regex, filter, fail2ban

Regex

> ```
> [Definition]
> failregex = AUTHFAIL: .* ip=<HOST>
> ignoreregex =
> datepattern = %%Y%%m%%d-%%H:%%M:%%S
> ```

Jail

> ```
> jail.local
>
>  [xrdp]
> enabled = true
> port = 3389
> filter = xrdp
> logpath = /var/log/xrdp-sesman.log
> maxretry = 3
> bantime = 1800
> ```

log I am monitoring

> ```
> [20230402-19:05:40] [INFO ] AUTHFAIL: user=qwqwe ip=192.168.50.76 time=1680480340
> ```

Using Ubuntu 20.04 THANKS!!!

In fail2ban.log I do not get a message that it is working. i need help

Answer (score 2):

I am using Fail2ban v1.0.2 & Package: xrdp (0.9.21.1-1) on Debian.

My filter & jail.local config are exactly the same as yours, except that I am using my defaults for maxretry and bantime.

Fail2ban works properly with those configurations for me and bans like it should.

You should verify your jail is starting correctly in fail2ban.log:

```
2023-04-04 18:59:40,573 fail2ban.jail           [8705]: INFO    Jail 'xrdp' started
```

and run fail2ban-client to test for configuration problems:

```
$ fail2ban-client -t
```